# How to add an Android AudioEffect LowPass Filter?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audiotrack, lowpass-filter, audioeffect

I'm trying to add a LowPass filter to an AudioTrack or MediaPlayer, but I don't think it exists.

It seems that the Android Audio Framework, unlike the Web Audio API and iOS, doesn't provide such effect at all: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect

Is it possible at all in this case to add a LowPass Filter or any BiquadFilter, for example?
Do I have to create my AudioEffect? I looked everywhere but couldn't find any.

I'm honestly not sure what to do or how to go about adding a simple LowPass Filter.

Anything would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in solution. You have to build your own Low-Pass Filter.

**But**: its not that difficult. Here is a very good reference with code examples on how to build:

[digital Butterworth and Chebyshev Filters](http://www.exstrom.com/journal/sigproc/)

Have fun!

Comment: Alright I'll look into it. Cheers